# Can a Django view receive a list as parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to submit a form (by POST) that will submit N (unknown) user_id's.
Can I make a view receive those ids as a list?

For example

```
def getids(request,list):

   for id in list:
       usr = User.objects.get(pk=id);
       //do something with it.
       usr.save()
```

Is

```
for id in request.POST['id']:
```

even possible?

I'm looking for the best accepted way.

Answer (score 5):

You should read about [QueryDict objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects):

```
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3')
>>> q.lists()
[('a', ['1', '2', '3'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Very close. The POST parameters are actually contained in a [QueryDict object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) in the request.

```
def getids(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for field in HttpRequest.POST:
            // Logic here
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are submitting lots of identical forms in one page you might find [Formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) to be the thing you want.

You can then make one Form for the userid and then repeat it in a Formset.  You can then iterate over the formset to read the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the form fields with some prefix you could filter later.

Say you use form fields with names like uid-1, uid-2, ... uid-n

Then, when you process the POST you can do:

```
uids = [POST[x] for x in POST.keys() if x[:3] == 'uid']
```

That would give you the values of the fields in the POST which start with 'uid' in a list.

Comment: That should be x[:3], not x[:2]

Answer (score 0):

`QueryDict`'s [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) is what you're looking for.

From the docs:

```
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1', mutable=True)
>>> q.update({'a': '2'})
>>> q.getlist('a')
['1', '2']
```